# Only select rows where the same value is present in more than two rows

Tags: r

I have a dataframe as follows:

```
ID    Text    
1234   fsfds
1234   sgge
1234   adfdf
543    sfsf
23     qfsg
23     swfr
6435   iuhg
6435   sonf
6435   ooos
```

I'd like to select only those columns where the ID is present three times or more so the **expected output** is

```
ID    Text
1234   fsfds
1234   sgge
1234   adfdf
6435   iuhg
6435   sonf
6435   ooos
```

How do I select columns with the same value in one column only?

I tried this but got an error

```
library(dplyr)
    myData %>% group_by(ID) %>%
      slice(sort(c(which(ID), which(ID) + 1)))

Error in slice_impl(.data, dots) : 
  Evaluation error: argument to 'which' is not logical.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want `filter()`.

```
library(dplyr)
myData %>% group_by(ID) %>% filter(n() > 2)
```

Only groups with more than 2 rows are kept.

Comment: OK also just solved it myself with ind1 <- myData[myData $ID == dplyr::lag(myData $ID),]